# How to find the average of previous sales at each time in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with four columns: date, wholesaler, product, and sales. I am looking for finding average of previous sales for each Product and Wholesaler combination at each date. It means what is the average previous sales of product 'A' at wholesaler 'B' at time 'C'.

For instance we know sales of product 'A' at wholesaler 'B' at Jan, Apr, May, Aug that are 100, 200, 300, 400 respectively. Let assume we do not have any record before Jan. So the average of previous sale of product 'A' in wholesaler 'B' at Apr is equal to 100/1, and at May is equal to (200+100)/2 and at Aug is (300+200+100)/3.

The following table shows my data:

```
date    wholesaler product  sales
12/31/2012  53929  UPE54     4
12/31/2012  13131  UPE55     1
2/23/2013   13131  UPE55  1156
4/24/2013   13131  UPE55     1
12/1/2013   83389  UPE54     9
12/17/2013  83389  UPE54     1
12/18/2013  52237  UPE54     9
12/19/2013  53929  UME24     1
12/31/2013  82204  UPE55     9
12/31/2013  11209  UME24     4
12/31/2013  52237  UPE54     1
```

Now I am using this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv',index_col='date')
df2 = df.groupby(['wholesaler','product'])['sales'].mean()
```

That gives an average sales for each wholesaler-product while I am looking for average of previous sales at each date.

```
wholesaler product   avg sales
    11209  UME24      4.00
    13131  UPE55    713.00
    22423  UME24      1.00
    24302  U4E16    121.00
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was quite tricky for me but works anyhow. Expecting more elegant solution from others.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')
df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv',index_col='date', parse_dates=[0], date_parser=dateparse)

expd_gb = df.reset_index().groupby(['wholesaler', 'product'])['sales'].apply(pd.Series.expanding)
idx = df.reset_index().groupby(['wholesaler', 'product', 'date'])['sales'].count().index

cnct = pd.concat([expd_gb.iloc[n].mean().shift(1) for n in range(len(expd_gb))])
cnct.index = idx

cnct.to_csv('TotalAvg.csv')
```

Result,

```
wholesaler  product  date      
11209       UME24    2013-12-31     NaN
13131       UPE55    2012-12-31     NaN
                     2013-02-23     1.0
                     2013-04-24     578.5
52237       UPE54    2013-12-18     NaN
                     2013-12-31     9.0
53929       UME24    2013-12-19     NaN
            UPE54    2012-12-31     NaN
82204       UPE55    2012-12-31     NaN
83389       UPE54    2013-12-01     NaN
                     2013-12-17     9.0
```

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate your help. It is an elegant solution!

Comment: Just one more question! I need to find previous average sales for last 52 weeks. As time goes the iteration of sales record is increase. I need to find out what is the average sales of last 52 weeks. It means at a certain date for instance 11/6/2015 what is the average sales of a product at certain wholesaler for last 52 weeks. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Ashkan Then you may better to use `.rolling` mean instead of expanding mean. Please check Rolling Windows of pandas Computational tools(http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#rolling-windows).

Comment: @ su79eu7k Thank you for your reply and very nice hint. I try to add `.rolling' to code to solve 52 weeks problem too.

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution

```
df = pd.read_csv('Sample.csv',index_col='date')
df2 = df.groupby(['wholesaler','product'])['sales'].apply(pd.expanding_mean)
```

Comment: Seems very good approach but `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` for me. Any idea? (pandas 1.18.0 says `FutureWarning: pd.expanding_mean is deprecated for Series and will be removed in a future version, replace with 
 Series.expanding(min_periods=1).mean()`. So I tried `df.groupby(['wholesaler','product'])['sales'].apply(pd.series.expanding.mean)` also, but no further progress...)

Comment: Thanks! such a good hint. But when I run it this error shows up:
raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: The new syntax (for 0.18.0) would be `apply( lambda x: x.expanding().mean() )`

Comment: The error is from setting the index to date, which is not unique (that's what the error message complains about).  Either don't set the index at all or just use `as_index=False` option of groupby.